# In GridView, when click on checkbox add values from label to TextBox using JavaScript in the same row of Grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have 3 columns in a GridView. The first column has CheckBox, Second column has outstanding amount due  in Label and Third column contains TextBox to pay Amount.

My problem is that TextBox should be filled with second column value when the checkbox is checked and textbox values should be cleared when checkbox uncheck.

Please refer java script code I have used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function SelectChange(ChkId, txt1, total) {
              var chk = document.getElementById(ChkId);
              UpdateField(ChkId, txt1, total)

          }

          function UpdateField(ChkId, txt1, total) {
              if (document.getElementById(ChkId).checked == true)
              {
                  var lblvalue = document.getElementById(total).value;
                  document.getElementById(txt1).innerHTML = lblvalue;
              }
              else
              {
                  document.getElementById(txt1).innerHTML = "0";
              }
          }

    </script>
```

In code behind...

```
protected void grdFeesCollection_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox txtPayment = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtPayment");
            Label lblDue = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDue");
            CheckBox chckSelecthead = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chckSelect");

            chckSelecthead.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:return SelectChange('" + chckSelecthead.ClientID + "','" + "','" + txtPayment.ClientID + "','" + lblDue.ClientID + "')";

            txtPayment.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript:return UpdateField('" + chckSelecthead.ClientID + "','" + txtPayment.ClientID + "','" + lblDue.ClientID + "')";

        }
    }
```

This is not returning any values to TextBox, That is the issue.

Comment: What exactly won't work ? Do you recive any javascript error ?

Comment: Actually not working. Not getting any output when click on checkbox

Comment: try it with 
chckSelecthead.Attributes["onclick"] = "SelectChange('" + chckSelecthead.ClientID + "','" + "','" + txtPayment.ClientID + "','" + lblDue.ClientID + "')";
if it won't work, post please the javascript error you recive

Comment: got error. Uncaught ReferenceError: UpdateField is not defined

Comment: When to click on checkbox error showing that **Uncaught ReferenceError: UpdateField is not defined** @Cyril

Comment: This won't make sense for me. What when you put the code directly in selectchange function? (they do the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e ) {
    if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow ) {
        Label    lblDue     =    (Label) e.Row.FindControl("lblDue");
        TextBox  txtPayment =  (TextBox) e.Row.FindControl("txtPayment");
        CheckBox chckSelect = (CheckBox) e.Row.FindControl("chckSelect");

        string js = string.Format( "javascript: return SelectChange( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}' ); ", 
                                    chckSelect.ClientID, 
                                    lblDue.ClientID,
                                    txtPayment.ClientID );

        chckSelect.Attributes[ "onclick" ] = js;
    }
}
```

---

JavaScript:

```
function SelectChange(ChkID, DueID, PaymentID) {

    var CheckBox = document.getElementById(ChkID);
    var Due = document.getElementById(DueID);
    var Payment = document.getElementById(PaymentID);

    Payment.value = (CheckBox.checked ? Due.textContent : "");
}
```

Comment: How can I loop through this grid to apply the change for all textboxes by checking or unchecking all textboxes simultaneously.

Comment: That is a bit more involved.  I've seen it implemented rather easily with jQuery.  Add a "CheckAll" checkbox to the header column and setting it's `onclick` attribute to a function that makes jquery calls to handle the toggling of the checkboxes and updating/clearing the Payment textboxes as needed.  Google `asp.net Gridview CheckAll` you'll find many examples